# Loop over bytes: suddenly integers

Tags: python-3.x

Python2: `[d for d in b'abc'] --> ['a', 'b', 'c']`

Python3: `[d for d in b'abc'] --> [97, 98, 99]`

How can I loop over bytes in Python3 and each iteration should get a byte string containing one character (like Python2 did)?

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
[chr(d) for d in b'abc']
```

Result

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: Not work for non-ASCII data.

Comment: @lilydjwg Since non-ASCII data is typically multiple bytes long, iterating over the data is something completely different than iterating over their bytes. A string `月女子` when converted to bytes looks like this: `b'\xe6\x9c\x88\xe5\xa5\xb3\xe5\xad\x90'`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the `byte-string` to normal string in Python 3.

```
[d for d in b'abc'.decode()]
```

Should return `['a', 'b', 'c']`

Comment: Need to encode back to bytes and that's what's asked for (but weird for non-ASCII data).

Answer (score -1):

You can simply convert the integers back to strings:

```py
[chr(d) for d in b'abc'] --> ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Or even to bytes:

```py
[chr(d).encode() for d in b'abc'] --> [b'a', b'b', b'c']
```

Comment: Not work for non-ASCII data.